# Sending image to webservice using asynctask

Tags: android, image, web-services, android-asynctask, uri

I have got an app that can take a picture and deliver me an uri of the given picture.
Next thing, I want to do is send this picture to my webservices.

But, Once i tried that, i got an error that i have had before, which relates to asynctask. So tried to work around it, i have got a HttpManager class which holds the information on how to connect to the webservice, the url itself and where it handles the image uri.

```
public static String uploadImageToWebservice(String uri, String imageUri) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    int responseCode = 0;
    String image = "";
    try {

        URL url = new URL(uri + imageUri);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        /*
        * String userpassword = adminUser + ":" + adminPassword; String
        * encodedAuthorization = DatatypeConverter
        * .printBase64Binary(userpassword.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        * connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " +
        * encodedAuthorization);
        */

        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        image = is.toString();
        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("URL", "failure response from server >" + e.getMessage()
                + "<");

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }

    }
    return image;
}
```

And this is how i handle this method in my activity.

```
private void submitImage(String uri) {
    HttpAsyncTask at = new HttpAsyncTask();
    at.execute(uri);

}

    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String image = HttpManager.uploadImageToWebservice(params[0],
                    params[1]);
            return image;
        }

    }
```

And then i call the submitImage method in the oncreate with the Uri of the webservice.

But I'm  kind of stuck on where to put in the uri of the image itself for it to be sent as well. I just feel like I'm missing something and i can't figure out where it is. Hopefully its to understand all of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use code for uploading image

```
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("sourcefile");
                    URL url = new URL("URL");

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);

                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                    // data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    // String serverResponseMessage = conn
                    // .getResponseMessage();

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                        statud = "uploaded";
                        // messageText.setText(msg);
                        // Toast.makeText(ctx, "File Upload Complete.",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // System.out.println("Uploaded successfyuly http: 200");
                        // recursiveDelete(mDirectory1);

                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
```

php code

```
<?php

   $uploads_dir = './images/';
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['bill']['tmp_name'];
   $pic_name = $_FILES['bill']['name'];

   if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir.$pic_name )) {
   echo "uploaded"; 
   }

?>
```

Comment: This won't work, because I'm working with android so I need to include asynctask. Otherwise i'll get an exception if not using it.

Comment: you have to use this code in doinbackground method in asynctask ok

Comment: I will try this soon!

Comment: There is so many variables that isn't stated in your code @raj  - could you help me out with that?

Comment: If you need to upload image to server first encode in to String using  Base64 and decode it in to image in server side.This will help to reduce memory exception handle in android application.